# PyQtGraph: Live video stream freezes using ImageView

Tags: pyqtgraph

Hi everyone,

I'm writing a GUI for a camera and I'd like to have a widget with the live stream from the camera.

Following one of the examples, I'm doing it this way:

```
def updateview():
    global img, camera
    img.setImage(camera.most_recent_image(camera.detector_shape))

win = QtGui.QWidget()

# Image widget
imagewidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
view = imagewidget.addViewBox()
view.setAspectLocked(True)
img = pg.ImageItem(border='w')
view.addItem(img)
view.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 512, 512))

layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(imagewidget, 1, 2, 3, 1)
win.show()

viewtimer = QtCore.QTimer()
viewtimer.timeout.connect(updateview)
viewtimer.start(0)

app.exec_()
viewtimer.stop()
```

This indeed works and I would be happy with it if it wasn't for the fact that I also need the intensity histogram on the side.

So I tried changing the first paragraphs like this:

```
def updateview():
    global img, camera
    img.setImage(camera.most_recent_image(camera.detector_shape), 
                 autoHistogramRange=False)

win = QtGui.QWidget()
img = pg.ImageView()
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(img, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

This only works for a few frames (I can see the images changing and the histogram moving accordingly) and then the whole GUI freezes. Has anyone seen this behaviour?

Thanks in advanced,

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: It is possible to use the histogram / contrast controls without ImageView. See: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/imageAnalysis.py

Regarding the freezing: If I run your code generating random data rather than pulling from a camera, it runs just fine. I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. Are you perhaps using multiple threads incorrectly? You may need to post a more complete example, and do some testing to determine where the program is hanging up.

Comment: Thank you Luke! Without ImageView, it doesn't freeze!