# PyQtGraph stops updating and freezes when grapahing live sensor data

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQt5 and pyqtgraph to plot live sensor data. This graph is part of a bigger PyQt5 application which is used to interact with various hardware and also visualize the sensor data.

**Background:** Below code is a very simplified example for the code that is responsible for querying the sensor for data and then plotting a graph of the instantaneous position and its moving average. The sensor is queried in a separate thread at every x ms intervals.

**Problem:**  The graphing and sensor reading works as expected. However, after running the application for a few seconds, the pyqtgraph stops updating and freezes. Once the graph freezes, the only time I see the graph refresh/update is if I try to resize the window or give focus to another window and refocus back to the graph window. In such cases the graph will be updated only once and it doesn't continue to refresh.

I have read other user having similar issue in links like below. However the proposed solution was not to update the GUI from a separate thread. In my case, I am NOT updating the graph from a separate thread. I am only using the separate thread to collect sensor data then emit a signal which with the new data. The updating of the graph occurs in the main thread.

- https://groups.google.com/g/pyqtgraph/c/ajykxBvysEc
- [pyqtgraph ImageView Freezes when multithreaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012643/pyqtgraph-imageview-freezes-when-multithreaded)

[image]

```py
import time 
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
import pyqtgraph as pg
import bottleneck as bn
import PyQt5

class MySensor():
    def get_position(self, mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1):
        # Random sensor data 
        return np.random.normal(mean,standard_dev,1)[0]

class SignalCommunicate(PyQt5.QtCore.QObject):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620056
    got_new_sensor_data = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float)
    position_updated = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

class LiveSensorViewer():

    def __init__(self, sensor_update_interval=25):
        # super().__init__()
        
        # How frequently to get sensor data and update graph 
        self.sensor_update_interval = sensor_update_interval

        # Init sensor object which gives live data 
        self.my_sensor = MySensor()
        
        # Init with default values
        self.current_position = self.my_sensor.get_position(mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1)
        self.current_position_timestamp = time.time()

        # Init array which stores sensor data 
        self.log_time = [self.current_position_timestamp] 
        self.log_position_raw = [self.current_position] 
        self.moving_avg = 5

        # Define the array size on max amount of data to store in the list 
        self.log_size = 1 * 60 * 1000/self.sensor_update_interval  

        # Setup the graphs which will display sensor data 
        self.plot_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.my_graph = self.plot_widget.addPlot(axisItems = {'bottom': pg.DateAxisItem()})
        self.my_graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.25)
        self.my_graph.addLegend()

        # Curves to be drawn on the graph 
        self.curve_position_raw = self.my_graph.plot(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw, name='Position raw (mm)', pen=pg.mkPen(color='#525252'))
        self.curve_position_moving_avg = self.my_graph.plot(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw, name='Position avg. 5 periods (mm)', pen=pg.mkPen(color='#FFF'))

        # A dialog box which displays the sensor value only. No graph. 
        self.my_dialog = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.verticalLayout = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.my_dialog)
    
        self.my_label = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.my_label)
        self.my_label.setText('Current sensor position:')

        self.my_sensor_value = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.my_sensor_value)
        self.my_sensor_value.setDecimals(6)

        self.my_dialog.show()

        # Signals that can be emitted 
        self.signalComm = SignalCommunicate()
         # Connect the signal 'position_updated' to the QDoubleSpinBox 
        self.signalComm.position_updated.connect(self.my_sensor_value.setValue)
        
        # Setup thread which will continuously query the sensor for data 
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=(self.my_sensor, self.sensor_update_interval))
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start() # Start the thread to query sensor data 

    def read_position(self, sensor_obj, update_interval ):
        # This function continuously runs in a seprate thread to continuously query the sensor for data 

        sc = SignalCommunicate()
        sc.got_new_sensor_data.connect(self.handle_sensor_data)

        while True:
            # Get data and timestamp from sensor 
            new_pos = sensor_obj.get_position(mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1)
            new_pos_time = time.time()

            # Emit signal with sensor data and  timestamp 
            sc.got_new_sensor_data.emit(new_pos, new_pos_time)

            # Wait before querying the sensor again 
            time.sleep(update_interval/1000)

    def handle_sensor_data(self, new_pos, new_pos_time ):

        # Get the sensor position/timestamp emitted from the separate thread 
        self.current_position_timestamp = new_pos_time
        self.current_position = new_pos

        # Emit a singal with new position info 
        self.signalComm.position_updated.emit(self.current_position)

        # Add data to log array 
        self.log_time.append(self.current_position_timestamp)
        if len(self.log_time) > self.log_size:
            # Append new data to the log and remove old data to maintain desired log size 
            self.log_time.pop(0)

        self.log_position_raw.append(self.current_position)
        if len(self.log_position_raw) > self.log_size:
            # Append new data to the log and remove old data to maintain desired log size 
            self.log_position_raw.pop(0)

        if len(self.log_time) <= self.moving_avg:
            # Skip calculating moving avg if only 10 data points collected from sensor to prevent errors 
            return 
        else:
            self.calculate_moving_avg()
        
        # Request a graph update 
        self.update_graph()

    def calculate_moving_avg(self):
        # Get moving average of the position 
        self.log_position_moving_avg = bn.move_mean(self.log_position_raw, window=self.moving_avg, min_count=1)

    def update_graph(self):
        self.curve_position_raw.setData(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw)
        self.curve_position_moving_avg.setData(self.log_time, self.log_position_moving_avg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    z = LiveSensorViewer()

    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 9):

I was able to find a solution to my original question. I have posted the solution below and elaborated the the reasons why the original issue was occurring.

**The issue**

The graph in the original question was freezing because the PyQtGraph was updated from a separate thread instead of the main thread. One can determine which thread a function is executing from by print the output of

```
threading.currentThread().getName()
```

In the original question, the call to `update_graph()` was being made from `handle_sensor_data()` which is running in a separate thread. The reason `handle_sensor_data()` is running in a separate thread is because the instance of the signal, `got_new_sensor_data`, was connected to the slot, `handle_sensor_data()`, inside the `read_position()`, which is also running in a separate thread.

**The solution**

The solution is to trigger a call to the `update_graph()` by emitting a signal, e.g. `self.signalComm.request_graph_update.emit()` from inside the `handle_sensor_data()`. This signal, `request_graph_update`, must be connected to the slot, `update_graph()`, from the main thread, i.e. inside `__init__()`.

Below is the full code of the solution.

```py
import time 
import numpy as np
import threading
from threading import Thread
import pyqtgraph as pg
import bottleneck as bn
import PyQt5


class MySensor():
    def get_position(self, mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1):
        # Random sensor data 
        return np.random.normal(mean,standard_dev,1)[0]

class SignalCommunicate(PyQt5.QtCore.QObject):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620056
    got_new_sensor_data = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float)
    position_updated = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    request_graph_update = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class LiveSensorViewer():

    def __init__(self, sensor_update_interval=25):
        # super().__init__()
        
        # How frequently to get sensor data and update graph 
        self.sensor_update_interval = sensor_update_interval

        # Init sensor object which gives live data 
        self.my_sensor = MySensor()
        
        # Init with default values
        self.current_position = self.my_sensor.get_position(mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1)
        self.current_position_timestamp = time.time()

        # Init array which stores sensor data 
        self.log_time = [self.current_position_timestamp] 
        self.log_position_raw = [self.current_position] 
        self.moving_avg = 5

        # Define the array size on max amount of data to store in the list 
        self.log_size = 1 * 60 * 1000/self.sensor_update_interval  

        # Setup the graphs which will display sensor data 
        self.plot_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.my_graph = self.plot_widget.addPlot(axisItems = {'bottom': pg.DateAxisItem()})
        self.my_graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True, alpha=0.25)
        self.my_graph.addLegend()

        # Curves to be drawn on the graph 
        self.curve_position_raw = self.my_graph.plot(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw, name='Position raw (mm)', pen=pg.mkPen(color='#525252'))
        self.curve_position_moving_avg = self.my_graph.plot(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw, name='Position avg. 5 periods (mm)', pen=pg.mkPen(color='#FFF'))

        # A dialog box which displays the sensor value only. No graph. 
        self.my_dialog = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.verticalLayout = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.my_dialog)
    
        self.my_label = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.my_label)
        self.my_label.setText('Current sensor position:')

        self.my_sensor_value = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.my_sensor_value)
        self.my_sensor_value.setDecimals(6)

        self.my_dialog.show()

        # Signals that can be emitted 
        self.signalComm = SignalCommunicate()
         # Connect the signal 'position_updated' to the QDoubleSpinBox 
        self.signalComm.position_updated.connect(self.my_sensor_value.setValue)
        # Update graph whenever the 'request_graph_update' signal is emitted 
        self.signalComm.request_graph_update.connect(self.update_graph)
        
        # Setup thread which will continuously query the sensor for data 
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=(self.my_sensor, self.sensor_update_interval))
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start() # Start the thread to query sensor data 

    def read_position(self, sensor_obj, update_interval ):
        # print('Thread ={}          Function = read_position()'.format(threading.currentThread().getName()))

        # This function continuously runs in a seprate thread to continuously query the sensor for data 

        sc = SignalCommunicate() 
        sc.got_new_sensor_data.connect(self.handle_sensor_data)

        while True:
            # Get data and timestamp from sensor 
            new_pos = sensor_obj.get_position(mean=0.0, standard_dev=0.1)
            new_pos_time = time.time()

            # Emit signal with sensor data and  timestamp 
            sc.got_new_sensor_data.emit(new_pos, new_pos_time)

            # Wait before querying the sensor again 
            time.sleep(update_interval/1000)

    def handle_sensor_data(self, new_pos, new_pos_time ):
        print('Thread ={}          Function = handle_sensor_data()'.format(threading.currentThread().getName()))
        # Get the sensor position/timestamp emitted from the separate thread 
        self.current_position_timestamp = new_pos_time
        self.current_position = new_pos

        # Emit a singal with new position info 
        self.signalComm.position_updated.emit(self.current_position)

        # Add data to log array 
        self.log_time.append(self.current_position_timestamp)
        if len(self.log_time) > self.log_size:
            # Append new data to the log and remove old data to maintain desired log size 
            self.log_time.pop(0)

        self.log_position_raw.append(self.current_position)
        if len(self.log_position_raw) > self.log_size:
            # Append new data to the log and remove old data to maintain desired log size 
            self.log_position_raw.pop(0)

        if len(self.log_time) <= self.moving_avg:
            # Skip calculating moving avg if only 10 data points collected from sensor to prevent errors 
            return 
        else:
            self.calculate_moving_avg()
        
        # Request a graph update 
        # self.update_graph()                     # Uncomment this if you want update_graph() to run in the same thread as handle_sensor_data() function 

        # Emitting this signal ensures update_graph() will run in the main thread since the signal was connected in the __init__ function (main thread)
        self.signalComm.request_graph_update.emit()     

    def calculate_moving_avg(self):
        print('Thread ={}          Function = calculate_moving_avg()'.format(threading.currentThread().getName()))
        # Get moving average of the position 
        self.log_position_moving_avg = bn.move_mean(self.log_position_raw, window=self.moving_avg, min_count=1)

    def update_graph(self):
        print('Thread ={}          Function = update_graph()'.format(threading.currentThread().getName()))
        self.curve_position_raw.setData(self.log_time, self.log_position_raw)
        self.curve_position_moving_avg.setData(self.log_time, self.log_position_moving_avg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    z = LiveSensorViewer()

    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this answer solved my same problem. I fixed by using a slot on the main thread to `.setData()` but used a QThread as the timer to emit() the data updates. thanks!